# how to obtain list of fields in class in java?

Tags: java

I want to retrieve list of member variables of a specified class along with other information like datatype, size, value,etc. This is possible using Reflection class. But is there any way other than Reflection class to get this information?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I'm aware of is via source-code analysis, with tools like [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes [`introspection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) may help you apart from `Reflection`

Comment: but I want to use this in my blackberry app and I am not using java beans. It is just a class with 10 member variables and for every object of it I want to retrieve members info and no. of members in that class may vary in future. There are three such classes for which I want to do this.

Comment: then what is the problem with `Reflection` ?

Comment: but there is no Reflection class in blackberry and I want to use the same code on android also

Answer (score 1):

Just use the methods provided by the field `class` of your class. See object [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. reflection, this is actually easiest way to do that
2. parsing source code using generated compiler (antlr project has java grammar file), it's a little bit more complicated and will require additional dependencies in your project, this is suitable only in case you have source code
3. reading java class file and analyzing it, the most complicated. you'll have to create a java bytecode parser to read binary file. But this could be the fastest way (no additional deps LALR-k parsing, no overhead like in reflection), you'll be in control what to read, how to read, could work with compiled java code.

The question is why do you think reflection is not suitable for you?
It made much faster in java 1.5 comparing to previous java releases.

Comment: I want class info. to do customized object serialization which I am going to use in android and blackberry app. But blackberry doesn't support java.lang.reflect package, so I am unable to get Field info. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils class is actually quite the helper in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons-lang package has a very useful tool: ReflectionToStringBuilder. Here is the link to javadoc: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html